# Getting posts by a specific user on a specific post

Tags: feature-request, api

Currently with the SE api, you can get all the answers on a specific question using `/question/ID/answers`. You can also get all the answers by a specific *user* on a post using `/users/ID/answers`.

The problem is I don't see anyway to get all the answers on a *specific* question by a *specific* user.

I do know that I can filter the api response but my target question is the [PPCG sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) in which there are much more than a 100 questions meaning I could possible have to do up to 19 requests to get all the answers considering the maximum page size is 100.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest thing that could work is using the [Excerpt Search](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search#order=desc&sort=activity&title=Sandbox%20for%20Proposed%20Challenges&user=40695&filter=default&site=meta.codegolf&run=true).

It is a little bit hacky because you have to *select* the question based on its full title but you can restrict the [search_excerpts](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/search-excerpt)'s that get returned to a single user.

[image: search form on api]

Here is a code snippet that demonstrates how you can use that call and process its results.

```js
var url = ['https://api.stackexchange.com/',
           '2.2',
           'search',
           'excerpts'],
    query = [ 'order=desc', 
             'sort=activity',
             'title=Sandbox%20for%20Proposed%20Challenges',
             'user=40695', 
             'site=meta.codegolf'],
    api = url.join('/') + '?' + query.join('&');

$(document).ready(function () {
  $.get(api, function(data) {
    var i, item;
    for(i = 0; i < data.items.length; i = i + 1) {
      item = data.items[i];
      $('#result').append(      $('<tr></tr>').append(
          $('<td></td>').append(
           $('<a></a>')
            .prop('href', 'https://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/' + item.answer_id)
            .text(item.answer_id)
          ),
          $('<td></td>').text(new Date(item.creation_date*1000).toDateString()),
          $('<td></td>').text(item.score)
        )
      );
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="result">
  <tr><th>answer</th><th>created</th><th>score</th></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, +1, but it doesn't look like `search_except` returns all the data I need (body_markdown to be specific). In the meanwhile I'll just set the page_size to 100.

Comment: @Downgoat No, but you can do a second call then to retrieve those, so you're down to two calls then and with a bit of luck no paging